# Links suddenly stopped working on rollover images

Tags: css, hyperlink, rollover

I'm having an issue with a few links on my site. They were working yesterday, and as of this morning are not. I haven't made any changes to the code and I've checked the existing code with a backup and it is identical. Any idea what could be going on?

Thanks!

[Live Link](http://www.swordandplough.com)

The bottom three rollover images "Lookbook" "Video" and "Heroes" are the ones causing the problem.

HTML

```
<div class="one-third-home column alpha">
<div class="homepage_images"><a title="Lookbook" href="http://www.swordandplough.com/pages/lookbook"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="one-third-home column center">
<div class="homepage_images2"><a title="Videos" href="http://www.swordandplough.com/pages/video"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="one-third-home column omega">
<div class="homepage_images3"><a title="Hero of the week" href="http://www.swordandplough.com/pages/hero-of-the-week"></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.homepage_images {
padding-top: 121.5%;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Lookbook.jpg?9318);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
  background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */


}
.homepage_images:hover {
padding-top: 121.5%;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Lookbook_black.jpg?8359);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
  background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */
  cursor: pointer;


}

.homepage_images2 {
padding-top: 121.5%;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Video.jpg?9318);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
  background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */

}
.homepage_images2:hover {
padding-top: 121.5%;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Video_black.jpg?8359);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
  background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */
    cursor: pointer;

}

.homepage_images3 {
padding-top: 121.5%;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Heroes.jpg?9318);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
  background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */



}
.homepage_images3:hover {
padding-top: 121.5%;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/5914/files/Heroes_black.jpg?8359);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;  /* Firefox 3.6 */
  background-position: center;  /* Internet Explorer 7/8 */
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Something has clearly changed. Your links work because of a small script 'clickdiv.js' which you're getting from the Shopify CDN. You're getting a lot of other scripts from there too. It's possible that one of those scripts has been changed and you now have a conflict where you didn't before.

Comment: Thanks @MikeW. Looks like there was a conflict with the app.js script.

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tags for the working sections surround an image tag which fills the entire width of the parent container, thereby making so that the anchor tag applies to the whole area of the image.  However in your non-working divs you are setting the image as the background of the div.  And then you have an empty anchor tag nested within that div.

By default anchor tags have the styling **display:inline**. As you have no content within your anchor, this results in your anchor tag having a 0px by 0px dimension which means that there is no clickable location which fires off the href of the anchor tag.

I would try wrapping your anchor tag around the divs -- homepage_images, homepage_images1, homepage_images3

Comment: Good point. Just adding `display:block;` to the anchor tags would fix the problem.

Comment: In this case, I do not believe simply adding display:block to the anchor would entirely fix the problem.  This would ensure the width filled the container, however, because there is no content within the anchor tag, I believe the height would remain 0px which still results in an un-clickable area

Comment: It worked in my test, but yes it would be better to specify a height and width of 100%, or do as you suggest and wrap the anchors around the divs.

Comment: Technically correct, but not relevant here since the `clickdiv.js` script handles the click on the `<div>` and redirects based on the link it finds inside.

Comment: @MikeW Ah, nice catch. It seems to be working now. It must have just been a glitch on shopify's side.